# Unable to assign property values from profiles to .properties file from pom.xml using Maven

Tags: java, maven, filtering, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I am trying to assign values from pom.xml profile to .properties file.

I am able to invoke profile which I can see from maven-help-plugin and able to load properties using properties.load but values are displaying as ${env},${url} in console instead of actual values from profile.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

**My Properties file:**

[image]

**Console log:**

[image]

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>InteractSeleniumProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Integrated</id>
            <activation>
               <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <env>SIT1</env>
                <url>sit1.com</url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Independent</id>
            <activation>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <env>SIT2</env>
                <url>sit2.com</url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build> 
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>show-profiles</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suitexml}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <debugMode>${debugMode}</debugMode>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <screenShots>${screenshots}</screenShots>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>   
</project>
```